# Value doesn't update immidiately inside onSuccessListener

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, the user registers with Firebase authentication system, using email and password. After that, when he tries to login, he has to complete the second phase of registration (he has to fill 3 more fields in **gotoCreateProfileActivity** activity). There are 2 cases:

1. If he logins and hasn't completed those fields, he is navigated to **gotoCreateProfileActivity**.
2. If he has completed those fields, he is navigated to **MenuActivity**.

To check this, I retrieve the *username* field from firebase, and check if it is *null*. If it is, `isFilled` remains false (it is initialized as false outside of functions. I don't show it in the question). Otherwise, I update `isFilled=true`. That happens here:

```kotlin
private fun isRegistrationCompleted() = runBlocking {
    val docRef = db.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser?.uid.toString())
    docRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapShot ->
            if (documentSnapShot.data!!.getValue("username") != null) {
                isFilled = true
                Log.d("Login", "11+++ ${isFilled}")
            }
        }
    Log.d("Login", "22++++ ${isFilled}")
}
```

Next, I check if `isField` is true or not, and navigate user to the right activity:

```kotlin
// this is inside OnCreate function
loginButton.setOnClickListener {
    authenticateWithFirebase(emailField.text.toString(), passwordField.text.toString())
    isRegistrationCompleted()
    Log.d("Login", "33+++ ${isFilled}")
    if (isFilled) {
       gotoMenuActivity()
    } else {
        gotoCreateProfileActivity()
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, I am using tags to check when does the value `isFilled` is updated.
The expected outcome is:

```
D/Login: 11++++ true
D/Login: 22+++ true
D/Login: 33+++ true
```

But the results are:

```
D/Login: 22++++ false
D/Login: 33+++ false
D/Login: 11+++ true
```

So I assume that this block of code:

```
if (isFilled) {
       gotoMenuActivity()
    } else {
        gotoCreateProfileActivity()
    }
```

is being executed before `isFilled` has been updated to true.

I have tried co-routine, but haven't succeed to fix the problem.

Comment: While `isRegistrationCompleted` runs blocking the `33+++` is not part of that block, so it runs on the main thread before `isRegistrationCompleted` completes.

Comment: A listener is a callback that is called in the future, so this is expected. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57330766/506796). Please share how you tried to use a coroutine and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I forgot to remove `runBlocking` from previous atemp to use co-routine.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I prefer to do this without co-routines. I tried co-routines because I couldn't find another way. Can it be done sequential somehow?

Comment: Coroutines are the only way to do it sequentially (aka synchronously). The question I linked shows how to do it without coroutines by using callbacks.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks. I did it with callbacks using the link above.

Comment: Firebase API is asynchronous. You might also be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).